# Tools for writing a compiler for DSL

Tags: java, dsl

I am going to start wrting compiler for my textual Domain specific Language. As I know, some people suggest ANTLR is good for writing compiler. There are other tools also available. But, I am not sure, which one is good for me. Should I start with ANTLR or other new tools with good documents.

Kindly advice me  on this.

Comment: All depends on your language grammar's type

Comment: Everybody thinks a parser is what you need.  Necessary sure.  Sufficient, no.  You need more machinery to build good analysis/transformation/compiler tools.  See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html

Comment: @GETah : Kindly eloborate with one simple example.

Comment: @PankeshPatel Check this out for more info on different types of context free grammars http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar

Comment: Thanks GETah and Ira Baxter,  I am thinking that I should start with ANTLR first. BTW, I am going to attend this summer school on DSLs. (https://fmse.info.uaic.ro/events/SSLF12/) Any body interested ?

Comment: This question is impossible to answer in its current form. Do you require an external DSL, or would an internal DSL written in Groovy, JRuby, JavaScript, etc. suffice? If not, ANTLR is a fine place to start, or you could use one of the language workbench-style products around these days.

Comment: I am implementing an external DSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you could take a look at [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), *the* parser compiler for Java, which supposedly "makes building custom DSLs a breeze".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the planned complexity of your DSL, you may want to take a look at the Groovy language. It's a dynamic JVM language that you can mix freely with Java. There's quite a lot of documentation and examples out there to get you started on writing DSLs with Groovy.